# how loop in mat option material

Tags: angular, angular-material

i would like factorie my snippet:

```js
  public debutHeureJ: number = 8;//heure du début d'ouverture
  public finHeureJ: number = 17;//heure de la fin de journée
  public optionHeure: Array<number>;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
    for(let i=this.debutHeureJ ; i <this.finHeureJ;i++)
    {
      this.optionHeure.push(i);
    }
  }
```

```html
   <mat-select placeholder="debut du rendez-vous" formControlName="heureDeb">
        <mat-option>None</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="8">8H</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="9">9H</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="10">10H</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="11">11H</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="12">12H</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="13">13H</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="14">14H</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="15">15H</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="16">16H</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="17">17H</mat-option>
```

I would use *nfFor with angular
but variable i in not push I have this error:

```
AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

How I must do right code ?
thank's for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your array:
`optionHeure: Array<number>=[]`;

Comment: thank i forgot initialise table empty